# Linear Algebra operators.

Tags: linear-algebra

I am looking for an example of a Hermitian operator $T$ on a ﬁnite dimensional inner product space $V$ such that there does not exist a Hermitian operator $U$ on $V$ with $T = U^2$.

Also, what  condition  can be imposed on the eigenvalues of a Hermitian operator $T $ that will guarantee the existence of a self-adjoint operator $U$ on $V$ with $T = U^2$?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose U is a $2\times 2$ Hermitian operator

$U = \begin{bmatrix} a & b+ci\\ b-ci& d \end{bmatrix}$

$U^2 = \begin{bmatrix} a^2+b^2+c^2& (a+d)b + (a+d)ci\\ (a+d)b - (a+d)ci & b^2+c^2+d^2 \end{bmatrix}$

If $T$ has entries on the main diagonal has entries that are less than zero, then there can be no Hermitian $U$ such that $U^2 = T$